# Quicker if statements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

I am trying to create an iOS app which involves one main if statement to check if a text box contains certain text. I would like to check for multiple instances of a certain word but I don't want to do multiple if statements as this will dramatically slow down the performance of the app.

How can I check if a word matches that of a word in an NSArray, and if it does, return a NSString associated with that word in another text box?

Comment: Write it the way you think will be slow, and if it's slow, post the code.  It might not be as slow as you think it will be -- how many words are you talking about?

Comment: Have you tested the multiple `if` statements to see if they really are slow? Because that seems very unlikely....

Comment: There will be several hundred. It'll be like a question and answer service. You ask a question in a text box, press go and it checks to see if a word exists in the text box and if it does, it returns a value

Comment: ...Try a dictionary/hash table.

Comment: I sense from your comment that you should have a database (probably SQLite3) and use a `SELECT` query to retrieve your text that contains part or all the entered text in the text box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `NSDictionary` of the words you are checking against mapped against the `NSString` you want returned when that word is entered:

```
NSDictionary *words = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"word1", @"result1",
    @"word2", @"result2",
    /*etc*/
    nil];

NSString *wordFromTextBox = ...;
NSString *result = [words objectForKey:keyword];
if (result != nil)
{
    // use result
}
else
{
    // word wasn't something we expected
}

// Some time later
[words release];
```

EDIT: To iterate over the list so you can test if the *keywords* are contained in the textbox, you can do the following (assume `words` and `wordFromTextBox` are set-up as before):

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [words keyEnumerator];
while ((NSString *keyword = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil)
{
    if ([wordFromTextBox rangeOfString:keyword].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"The text box contains keyword '%@'", keyword);
        NSString *result = [words objectForKey:wordFromTextBox];
        // Use the result somehow
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @objc-obsessive I missed out the `alloc` in my first edit!  I've fixed it now.

Comment: how can I use this to check if "word1" is in the search textbox, whilst other words can be around it. i.e. it would still detect this; "This is word1" even though it has other words

Comment: @objc-obsessive That requires you to *iterate* over each of the keys in the `NSDictionary` and test if the key-word appears in the search text.  That won't be nearly as quick.  It really requires a new question.

Comment: How long would it take (roughly) to check through 100 keys for example? And could you tell me here (pretty please!)

Comment: @objc-obsessive 100 values wouldn't take long at all.

Comment: OK, could you provide an example for the iterate version? Thanks!

Comment: I've added that code but 'keyword' just returns the last key?

Comment: The app freezes when trying to do this - is there another way of doing it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10195/discussion-between-objc-obsessive-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a NSMutableDictionary/NSDictionary.  The dictionary keys will be the words you're looking for.  The values will be the words you wish to return.  Once you've got the dictionary setup simply call `[dict valueForKey:textbox.text]`.  The dict will return nil if the entry isn't in there, so you can test for that condition.  All in all, I think this is probably the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

for array, 
you can get an idea from this code:

```
NSArray* myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four", nil];
NSString* stringToSearch = @"four";
NSUInteger indexPositionInArray = [myArray indexOfObject:stringToSearch];
NSLog(@"position in array: %i", indexPositionInArray);
if (indexPositionInArray !=  NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"String found in array: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPositionInArray]);
}

NSString* stringToSearch2 = @"fourrrr";
NSUInteger indexPositionInArray2 = [myArray indexOfObject:stringToSearch2];
NSLog(@"position in array: %i", indexPositionInArray2);
if (indexPositionInArray2 !=  NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"String found in array: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPositionInArray]);
}
```